# When changing from excel 97-2003 ETL displays an error message

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, visual-studio, etl

Excel connection manager won´t allow me to switch the Excel version. I'll attach the error messages. Thank You.

*Screen Shots*

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the driver for Access 2013 to be compatible with the latest Excel documents. Careful to install the correct version (32 bit vs. 64 bit):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358

Comment: I installed the package and I still get the same error. I installed the 64 bit version because that is what my office runs on. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: But is Visual Studio 64 bit? (hint: no) It's a pain to uninstall and reinstall the 32 and 64 bit driver while testing but that's what I had to do.

Comment: But it won´t let me install the 32 bit version because it says I have 64 bit office versions installed.